# Problema con adaptador de un recyclerview android estudio

Tags: android

como ven al seleccionar un item se cambia a negro indicando que se ha seleccionado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el problema es que al seleccionar el otro item, el anterior queda marcado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo una lista de 10 textos es un menu con opciones al dar click en un item este cambia a color negro indicando que se ha seleccionado ese item, ahora el problema es como hago al seleccionar otro item, el item anterior se ponga en blanco y el que recien seleccione se haga negro, se que al introducir los objetos de mi vista al adaptador yo puedo modificar esos objetos y hasta cuando uso el clik onlistener puedo cambiar el color de ese objeto seleccionado, quiero saber como puedo manipular todos los objetos una vez cargados, por ejemplo una vez que el adaptador se ha cargado, poder manipular los objetos individualmente, he tratado de conseguir la posicion del item pero no se como manipular esos objetos una vez cargado el:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final AdaptadorMenuOpciones.ViewHolder holder, int position)
```

mi adptador

```
public class AdaptadorMenuOpciones extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorMenuOpciones.ViewHolder> {
    private List<ItemsMenuOpciones> list;
    private Context context;

    public AdaptadorMenuOpciones(Context context, List<ItemsMenuOpciones> list){
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AdaptadorMenuOpciones.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.vista_menu_opciones, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final AdaptadorMenuOpciones.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        String Opciones = list.get(position).getNombreOpcion();
        holder.textViewOpciones.setText(Opciones);
        holder.textViewOpciones.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

       

        holder.linearlayoutBordeBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> {

            holder.textViewOpciones.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        });

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView textViewOpciones;


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewOpciones = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewOpciones);

        }
    }


}
```

alguna persona que sea experto manipulando los adaptadores que me ayude a entender esto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes añadir al objeto ItemsMenuOpciones el atributo

```
Boolean isSelected = false; // por defecto.
```

Cuando se hace click en un item, la activity que tiene la lista recibe este click con un listener que debes añadir por constructor, recorre la lista y pone todos los isSelected a false excepto el item de la posición seleccionada que será true.  Entonces se la pasa al adapter a través de un método que debes crear, por ej.

```
public void update(ItemsMenuOpciones items) {
  this.list = items;
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Y el ViewHolder que es el que pinta la ui, decidirá si el color es blanco o negro para el fondo en función del valor de isSelected.

Con este approach no es necesario recibir la lista por constructor.  Como consejo también puedes evitar pasar el context, ya que el parámetro ViewGroup parent del método onCreateViewHolder, ya contiene el context (todas las vistas tienen un context).

Por último, para que el pintado sea más eficiente, mira el DiffUtils y, cuando lo tengas, implementa también el payload, que deberá cambiar sólo el color de fondo porque el texto no cambia.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema pasa porque le estas asignando el color al evento **click**, por lo tanto cada **item** que marques se pintara del color entonces lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente:

En primer lugar agrega un booleano en tu modelo:

```
 boolean isSelect = false;
```

Agrégalo también crea su método isSelect y setSelect:

```
public boolean isSelect() {
    return isSelect;
}

public void setSelect(boolean select) {
    isSelect = select;
}
```

Luego dirígete a tu **adapter** y crea una instancia de tu modelo:

```
final Modelo modelo = MiLista.get(position);
```

Bajo dicha instancia antes del metodo onclick asigna un color por defecto:

```
holder.view.setBackgroundTintList
(ColorStateList.valueOf(modelo.isSelect() ? Color.GRAY : Color.rgb(0, 151, 167)));
```

Esta es la forma en la que yo lo hago te recomiendo hacerlo de esta manera solo busca el RGB del color que deseas.

Por último dentro del método Onclick asigan la propiedad isSelect

```
modelo.setSelect(!modelo.isSelect());
holder.view.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(modelo.isSelect() ? Color.GRAY : Color.rgb(0,151,167)));
```

Y eso seria todo espero te funcione, cualquier duda házmela saber, saludos!

Comment: una pregunta final Modelo modelo = MiLista.get(position); el Model me sale en rojo en la onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final AdaptadorMenuOpciones.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

Comment: Hola @lidershinobi no veo porque deba darte un error, veo que tu modelo se llama ItemsMenuOpciones por lo tanto debería ser así -> **final ItemsMenuOpciones listmenuopciones = list.get(position);** luego utilizar la variable listmenuopciones en lugar de modelo